# Why is Wolfram Alpha giving incorrect result for Stirling's approximation

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, wolfram-alpha

Trying this: limit (n!)/(((n)^(n+0.5))(e^-n)) as n->infinity, 
in Wolfram Alpha gives zero even though it should give $\sqrt(2\pi)$.

I am especially surprised that it wasn't recognised as a form of Stirling's formula.

Any ideas?

**Edit:**
As per the comment below, replacing 0.5 by 1/2 solves the problem, so I suppose that the question now is, why does Wolfram Alpha compute the two seemingly equivalent forms of the same limit to give quite different results?

Comment: replacing $0.5$ by $1/2$ should help,

Comment: @RaymondManzoni Why does this make such a difference... why does WA apparently do a different calculation when making this replacement

Comment: @JohnDon simple question, simple answer: bugs.

Comment: I obtained [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20%28n!%29%2F%28%28%28n%29%5E%28n%2B0.5%29%29%28e%5E-n%29%29%20at%20infinity) for $0.5$. Note that the expansion appears right but alpha appears unible to simplify it further. When you introduce a numerical value part of symbolic evaluation may be lost as here...

Comment: @JohnDon Also see here why using 0.5 sometimes gives a wrong answer: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/112640/how-to-calculate-accurate-answer-in-mathematica